# how to take the backup of sql compact database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created a C# windows application with vs2010 and I'm using a SQL Server CE database. I'm looking for a way to backup my database programmatically.

Is there a way to export/import my entire database (as a .sdf file) or just copy it to another location and then import it and replace the current one?Could anyone provide me the code in order to do this?

I'm relatively new to this but I'm guessing this is not something as difficult as it sounds. I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's file based, so just stop accessing it and copy the file?

Answer (score 0):

For this task we use the [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) objects that have access to backup/restore functions using asp.net code.

Base on the article [How to: Back Up Databases and Transaction Logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms162166(v=sql.90).aspx) here is a part of the sample that make the backup:

```
// Create the Backup SMO object to manage the execution
Backup backup = new Backup();

// Add the file to backup to
backup.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(backupPath, DeviceType.File));

// Set the name of the database to backup
backup.Database = databaseName;

// Tell SMO that we are backing up a database
backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

backup.Incremental = false;

// Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
backup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

// Begin execution of the backup
backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is Is SQL can make backup then yes. I do not have test it on CS, but I work with that on MSSQL. If SQL CE have the "**SQL Server VSS writer**" as service up and running yes it can.